# Efficiently replace strings in 20k potential matches (Python)

Tags: python, performance

I want to replace substrings of a string and want to check against 20k+ candidates.

Is there a more efficient way than to split the 20k into subgroups of 900 candidates and Loop over them?

**This is my function:**

```
def replaceNames(mailString, nameList, replacement=" Nachname"):
    anzNames = len(nameList)
    seq = np.arange(start=0, stop=anzNames, step=900).tolist()
    seq.append(anzNames)
    for i in range(0, len(seq) - 1):
        tempNamesString = "|".join(nameList[seq[i]:seq[i + 1]])
        mailString = re.sub(tempNamesString, replacement, mailString)
    return (mailString)
```

thanks!

Comment: Can you provide an example input and output for this function? I'm struggling to follow what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion are:

1. Use `string` manipulation instead of using `re` (regex) where possible as it is faster.

   ```
   # Sample string of 1 million "my_rand_str"
   In [9]: x = ["my_rand_str"] * 1000000 

   In [10]: %%time                                                                                                             
       ...: replaced = [a.replace("str", "replaced") for a in x]                                                               
       ...:                                                                                                                    
       ...:                                                                                                                
   Wall time: 219 ms                                                                            

   In [11]: %%time                                                                                                             
       ...: replaced =  [re.sub("str", "replaced", a) for a in x]                                                             
       ...:                                                                                                                    
       ...:                                                                                                                
   Wall time: 1.33 s
   ```
2. If you insist using regex, use pre-compiled regex

   ```
   In [25]: tobe_replaced = re.compile("str")

   In [28]: %%time
       ...: replaced = [tobe_replaced.sub("replaced", a) for a in x]
       ...:
       ...:
       ...:
   Wall time: 1.02 s
   ```
3. If possible do it over one big string instead of looping it through since loop is more expensive.

   ```
   In [29]: %%time
       ...: replaced = tobe_replaced.sub("replaced", "\n".join(x)).split("\n")
       ...:
       ...:
   Wall time: 291 ms

   In [30]: %%time
       ...: replaced = "\n".join(x).replace("str", "replaced").split("\n")
       ...:
       ...:
       ...:
   Wall time: 132 ms
   ```

Hope this helps.